# How define a CDATA type in XSD so user doesn't have to escape characters or use "<![CDATA" tag?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, cdata

I have an XSD that defines an element "password". I want to allow any character there. Currently, I have the element defined as an `xs:string` and the user has to either escape the string (e.g. `myP&amp;ssword`) or enclose it in a CDATA tag (e.g. `<![CDATA[myP&ssword]]>`).

Is there a way to define an XSD so it won't require either of those but won't fail on validation?

XSD Element:

```
<xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" />
```

XML That throws the error:

```
<password>myP&ssword</password>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. The schema may specifies rules which define if a XML document is valid with respect to these rules, but it still requires the document to be well-formed.

From the XML schema [recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#intro-purpose):

> Any application that consumes **well-formed XML** can use the formalism
>   defined here to express syntactic, structural and value constraints
>   applicable to its document instances.